How to resize the highlighted partition?
After reducing the size of 230.55 I am trying to add 151.45 to the highlighted partition (92.60GiB).
In the image below, I'm logged into Ubuntu, and using Gparted.
Can't find how to do this anywhere. Any ideas ?


You can't directly add end-of-drive free space to a partition where the free space isn't next to the partition.  You also have a problem - you have a 2GB NTFS partition right next to it.
Note that any changes to partitions has the risk of damaging your data.

You'll need to load up into an Ubuntu installer disk in "Try Ubuntu" mode to do anything.  Make sure you back up critical data in case you mess up in these steps, there's very little recovery if you screw this up otherwise.

Once you're in the Live environment and have loaded the gparted tool, make sure that your ext4 partition at /dev/nvme0n1p5 is unmounted (if it has a key symbol it's mounted, right click it and choose "Unmount").

Right click the /dev/nvme0n1p5 partition and choose "Resize/Move".  Drag it to the far right so the empty space is to the left of the partition.  Once you've done this, apply the changes and wait a while, because it will do a full data move on disk.  DO NOT turn off your system, because otherwise you will lose your data.

Once the previous step applies, select your 1GB NTFS partition at /dev/nvme0n1p4 and do the same thing as in step 2, but for this NTFS partition.

After moving your 1GB NTFS partition, right click your NTFS partition at /dev/nvme0n1p3 and hit "Resize/Move" and resize the partition to fill your space, then apply the changes.


You should have your NTFS partition you want expanded properly expanded now. Note that because of step 2 it will take some time for this to complete and you MAY have problems if your system fails during the process, because you'll screw up your Ubuntu environment.

ok take your time, i'd appreciate some image or marks over my own image, or just what you think is right.

@MahNeh I don't ahve images at the moment, but I gave indepth instructions of what to click.  I'm not in front of my Ubuntu VMs at the moment to make image selections for examples (because I don't have NTFS partitions like you do as LInux is my daily driver).  I'll add them tomorrow when I'm back in front of a system I can mess with.

can i unmount ntfs partitions, i don't see this option if I right click? NP the post is quite clear

@MahNeh yes, by default they shouldn't mount even on a Live environment, but same thing as for the ext4 partition you have to unmount the partition if it ihas a lock.  It's still the same step in the gparted tool to unmount for NTFS as it is for ext4.  And much the same process but we want to make sure you Linux is moved fully first before we touch the Windows partitions

everything worked, thanks mate.

@MahNeh You're welcome.  I'll still add images tomorrow.
